# Config Spring boot project

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, h2

I have problems with spring boot. I have created a simple project example to check if the h2 database works. The result is not working.
Could you have a look what I am doing wrong?

Database

```
public class DatabaseInit implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {

        userRepository.save(new User("Aonso"));
        userRepository.save(new User("Jordan"));
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class DemoController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/users")
    public Collection<User> getUsers(){
        return this.userRepository.findAll();

    }

}
```

User.java

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String name;

    public User(){}

    public User(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

UserRespository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

App

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be much more effective if you'd share the actual project, that way we can run it and see what's wrong. All the code you've pasted seems ok but you're not pasting the most important: what is the error?

Comment: Thanks, you can download the project here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qr29232jif8bbqb/AADLMgM7uszGjxHXYKhrqLLHa?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating mixed package structure for your project. Your `@SpringBootApplication` is in `com.example` and your controllers are in `demo.controllers`. Spring Boot enables classpath scanning in its package and all sub-packages unless configured differently. It won't find your controllers (there's no reason for Spring Boot to start scanning the entire classpath).

We are actually explaining this (and much more) in a university session we gave at Devoxx this month so you may [want to check it out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uof5h-j0IeE) (check around 5:00 for the component scan explanation).